# How can I slice the high-order multidimeonal array (or tensor) on the specific axis in Julia?

Tags: multidimensional-array, julia, tensor

I am using `Julia1.6`

Here, `X` is a `D`-order multidimeonal array.
How can I slice from `i` to `j` on the `d`-th axis of `X` ?

Here is an exapmle in case of `D=6` and `d=4`.

```
X = rand(3,5,6,6,5,6)
Y = X[:,:,:,i:j,:,:]
```

`i` and `j` are given values which are smaller than 6 in the above example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the built-in function `selectdim`

```
help?> selectdim
search: selectdim

  selectdim(A, d::Integer, i)

  Return a view of all the data of A where the index for dimension d equals i.

  Equivalent to view(A,:,:,...,i,:,:,...) where i is in position d.

  Examples
  ≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡

  julia> A = [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8]
  2×4 Matrix{Int64}:
   1  2  3  4
   5  6  7  8

  julia> selectdim(A, 2, 3)
  2-element view(::Matrix{Int64}, :, 3) with eltype Int64:
   3
   7
```

Which would be used something like:

```
julia> a = rand(10,10,10,10);

julia> selectedaxis = 5
5

julia> indices = 1:2
1:2

julia> selectdim(a,selectedaxis,indices)
```

Notice that in the documentation example, i is an integer, but you can use ranges of the form `i:j` as well.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to just slice on a single axis, use the built in `selectdim(A, dim, index)`, e.g., `selectdim(X, 4, i:j)`.

If you need to slice more than one axis at a time, you can build the array that indexes the array by first creating an array of all `Colon`s and then filling in the specified dimensions with the specified indices.

```
function selectdims(A, dims, indices)
   indexer = repeat(Any[:], ndims(A))
   for (dim, index) in zip(dims, indices)
       indexer[dim] = index
   end
   return A[indexer...]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
idx = ntuple( l -> l==d ? (i:j) : (:), D)
Y = X[idx...]
```

Comment: Add more details to explain your answer